Recurrence relation problem from discrete mathematics
Solve the recurrence relation with $a_{0} = 1$ and
$a_{1} = 2$
$$
\mbox{and}\quad a_{n} = \frac{2a_{n-1}^{2}}{a_{n - 2}}\,,
\quad n = 3,4,5,\ldots 
$$
Hint: Logarithmize the equation

I usually make a characteristic polynomial, calculate the roots and solve with
$$
C_1x_1^n + C_2x_2^n\ \mbox{or} (C_1 + nC_2)x^n
\quad\mbox{if}\ x_1 = x_2 = x
$$
But doing this here gives $x^2 = 2x^2$ and logarithmizing didn't help either;
$$
\log\left(a_n\right) = 2\log\left(\,\sqrt{\,2\,}\,a_{n-1}\right) -\log\left(a_{n-2}\right)
$$
and idk what to do next.


Asking WolframAlpha yields $a(n) =\sqrt{2^{n(n-1)}}e^{an+b}$. The initial condition allows us to compute $a$ and $b$.

Welcome to Math S.E.  $l_n=2\log\sqrt2+2l_{n-1}-l_{n-2}$ is a non-homogenous linear recurrence relation

As J. W. Tanner began to answer : $\log(\sqrt{2}a_{n-1})=\log(\sqrt{2})+\log(a_{n-1})$. Set $\ell_{n}=\log(a_n)$.

Put $b_n=\frac a_n a_{n-1} $ to get geometric sequence.

Okk thanks everyone, I got it when converting it to a non-homogenous linear recurrence relation $l_n = \log{a_n}$, solving that I get $l_n = (C_1 + nC_2)1^n+\log{\sqrt{2}}n^2$ , the final solution is $a_n = 2^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$

$\log(2x^2)=\log 2+2\log x$.

An alternative solution here:
$a_n = \frac{2a_{n-1}^2}{a_{n-2}}$
Dividing $a_{n-1}$ on both sides,
$\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}= 2 \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}}$
So $\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}$ is a geometric sequence.
$\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}} = 2^n$ since $\frac{a_1}{a_{0}}=2$
Note that
$$a_{n} = \frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}} \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}} \cdots\frac{a_{2}}{a_{1}}\frac{a_{1}}{a_{0}} = 2^n 2^{n-1}\cdots 2^{1}=2^{n(n+1)/2}$$
